User acquisition zeroed when implementing consent mode
I have custom consent mode implementation for google analytics, using gtag.js.
Adding the relevant pieces of code:
  <!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
  <script data-category="analytics" data-service="Google Analytics" async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXXXXXXXX"></script>
  <script data-category="analytics" data-service="Google Analytics">
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag() {
      dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }

    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXXXXXX');

    gtag('consent', 'default', {
      'ad_user_data': 'denied',
      'ad_personalization': 'denied',
      'ad_storage': 'denied',
      'analytics_storage': 'denied',
      'wait_for_update': 500,
    });
  </script>

this is in my main index.html <head> then I am showing cookie consent banner and if I get a consent I set the values to (well, obviously based on user choices, but I checked that it will basically trigger these values if consent to everything is given).
    gtag('consent', 'update', {
      'ad_user_data': 'granted',
      'ad_personalization': 'granted',
      'ad_storage': 'granted',
      'analytics_storage': 'granted'
    });

This made my google analytics work ok. I also got rid of the nagging consent-mode related warning in the google analytics dashboard. However, after this one was implemented this completely zeroed my user acquisition report in google analytics (see image below).

I assume this is due to the way ad_user_data is delayed and probably the tracking data is lost. Or am I wrong? What can I do to get this back to working?

Which consent mode warning are you referring to? Did you make a change in the Google Analytics property/stream?
And which specific metrics no longer works?

I did not create new stream. The warning was visible in Google analytics -> Web stream details -> Consent settings. It is no longer displayed (since my changes). The metric that is almost zeroed is visualized in a graph in GA: Reports -> Acquisition -> User Acquisition

@Gengis I also attached image showcasing my broken metric

What if You would include google scripts only after consent was given with permissions granted straight away .
